# Magento 2: How to fix parse error?

Tags: magento2, error

How to fix parse error in `site.com/customer/section/load/`

There is an extra 'SS'.

[image]

Comment: It looks like this "ss" was added by accident to some source file. Try to search through the whole project in your IDE and find string like:

"ss"
'ss'

Comment: found a lot. specially the css.

Comment: I meant try to find `'ss'` or `"ss"` (including quotes).

Comment: Also please try to find `>ss`.

Comment: Just pass the string from this filter to remove ss manually using php -  `$str=ltrim($str,"ss");`

Comment: @VibhoreJain 'ss' added after return $resultJson->setData($response);

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to remove the die or print_r  on this page  site.com/customer/section/load/

If you are using Phpstorm you can easily see this error using the "Find in Files Option"
[image]

also, you can check the issue on this below path

vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Section/Load.php

Thank you.

Comment: checked vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Section/Load.php but nothing found 'ss'